# Cpanel forwarding email another email address

Tags: cpanel

I'm not sure if CPanel help is meant for serverfault or superuser so please forgive me if wrong.

I have a free fax to email number. Then I have a business where the fax is being send to employee 1, no I also want employee 2 to receive this fax. They both use different email addresses and my fax to email provider only forwards it to one email address. Now I create a rule in Cpanel, but then employee 1 does not receive the mail and only employee2 receives it.

Is this possible with CPanel, please let met know if this is not making sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to a mailing list.

You will have one e-mail, i.e. fax@example.com, and in CPanel you will set this up either as a list or a mailing group. In the group you will add the e-mail addresses for User 1 and User 2.

This feature is enabled by the hosting provider, and some charge additional for mailing list or groups. Both perform the same task, just slightly differently implemented.

You can get instructions on setting this up on CPanel [here](https://www.getsomesupport.com/manuals/cpanel/4.html). Scroll down a bit to find it.

Alternatively you can create a forwarder. You specify the same e-mail address to forward to every person you want to receive the e-mail.

You will need to change your e-mail address with the fax to e-mail company to the new e-mail address for this to work.

Comment: No I'm not referring to a mailing list. 2users each have there own email account on the server. Employee 1 needs to get the fax, but employee 2 also needs to get a copy of the fax, and if I set up a forwarder employee 2 will receive all of the mailos from employee 1 which I do not want

Comment: Your misunderstanding my suggestions. You need to create a **new** e-mail just for the fax, change it with the service provider, and then add both the users to the **new** e-mail address. So they will both receive the faxes. The forwarded source can be the same for different users, and does not have to be a mailbox.

Comment: Yes I did misunderstood, sorry for that ;-) Thanx this worked for me